# How can I combine error and access logs to create a custom format log in nginx?

Tags: nginx, logging, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am currently working on a project that requires logging to be very specifically formatted for the syslog server to interpret it correctly and to keep logging uniform across all projects.

I am aware of the limitations of combining error and access logs within nginx, but is there any way at all to combine information from both logs to produce a custom log? For example, I would like to get one log line like this: `[date and time] [$custom variable from outside nginx] [string message] [error log severity level (from the error log)] [http status code]`

I have researched a lot and couldn't find a way to do this. If it's not possible within nginx.conf, would I somehow be able to "output" both logs and manipulate them outside of nginx?